# Tool or web app for Microsoft Office documents preview

Tags: linux, microsoft-office, automation

I need a free tool for Linux or web service to create previews for MS Office documents automatically.

Tools I tried:

- https://docs.google.com/viewer
- LibreOffice
- unoconv

All of them have some problems with `.docx` documents and documents with complex format. Are there any other tools? I want to try something else and make better choice for my task.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does have it's own cloud document service, called Microsoft Office Web Apps: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps/. I would suspect it would be the best able of all tools to handle native MS formats like .docx.

Comment: Does this have API I can build in in my program? I saw this, but didn't find anything about it.

Comment: Whoops, I missed the automation tag in your question. I'm not sure about whether or not there's a comparable API to the Google Apps one. Does appear that as of 2010, there wasn't an API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058488/public-api-to-manage-documents-in-office-web-apps - might be a good question to ask over on SO.